# Is there a way to share my mobile screen with another Android phone like Netmeeting or Live Meeting?

Tags: screen-sharing

The requirement is similar to Netmeeting software where the screen of a desktop is shared and can be accessed for another system. Is is possible in a mobile device?

There should be no PC to Mobile connection.

Applicability: This can be used for verification of railway or air tickets where I can show my ticket shared with examiner's device instead of handing him the device.

Comment: FYI: It's better to ask question about a problem ("how can I share my screen...") than to ask for an app. In the latter case you've already selected your solution and the question becomes a "what's your favorite app that does X" poll question, which the [FAQ] tells us is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

If your device is rooted you could try to run a VNC Server (e.g. [droid VNC server BETA](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&feature=search_result)) and access it from the other mobile device with a VNC viewer of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ScreenMeet for Android.  It lets you share from your Android to any web browser.  The [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projector.screenmeet) is in the store.

Comment: What's your affiliation? Edit your post to include affiliation, app description, reviews, screenshots, etc. Otherwise your post will be [considered spam](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) according to SE rules.

Answer (score 0):

[join.me](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.logmein.joinme&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5sb2dtZWluLmpvaW5tZSJd) should work. Although i have never tried it myself for two android phones but it seems it may work. Try.